# How to tie a bullet release with a firing animation

Tags: 2d, animation, release, timing

Lets say you have an animation that you want to happen when firing a bullet.  How would you get the bullet to show up at the end of the animation.  The only thing I can figure out is to know the time length of the animation, and delay setting the bullets position and setting it active until that amount of time has passed.  I was just wondering if this is the best approach, how does everyone else handle this?

EDIT:  I think i'm having trouble wording the question properly.

[image: My Question]

Comment: Thanks! Many good ideas from all of you, I like the idea of using a callback.  I think I'll try and implement that, I really didn't want to rely on time tracking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fundamentally you're on the right track - you need to know how long an animation lasts to do this sort of thing. Animations are more than just a collection of frames, there is all sorts of other information around them that you need. E.g. how many frames are there, does the animation loop, how quickly does it play back (e.g. 10 animation frames per second or 25, or 60?). Every animation can be defined in terms of a few pieces of data, which some generalised animation code can look at and play back. You should be encapsulating the animation part in its own bit of code, which is aware of nothing except these animation definitions and how to display the individual image frames. That is, have an animation object which you can load, start playing, stop playing, and tell to render at a particular location on screen.

A flexible approach is to use a sort of animation definition to encapsulate this sort of information. So rather than just saying "animation X is all of these frames, just play through them", you get something a bit more complex.

E.g. with some sort of mocked up data format

```
animations =
{
  { name="walk", files="walk*.png", frameCount="12", loop="true" },
  { name="fire" files="fire*.png" frameCount="6",
       events = {
           { name="bulletLeavesGun", frame="4", param1="43", param2="30" }
       }
  }
}
```

So your code says something like:

```
currentAnimation = animations.Get("fire");
currentAnimation.Play();
```

How you detect events can either be with the animation code calling you back (i.e. when it detects a new event because the animation has played to a certain frame, it calls your game code to tell it about the new event), or by polling the animation like so:

```
List<Event> events = currentAnimation.EventsSinceLastCheck();
foreach (AnimationEvent event in events)
{
    if (event.name == "bulletLeavesGun")
    {
        Vector2 bulletPosition = new Vector2(event.param1, event.param2);
        Vector2 actualBulletPosition = new Vector2(
                 character.x + bulletPosition.x, 
                 character.y + bulletPosition.y);
        CreateBulletAt(actualBulletPosition);
    }
}
```

Points to note:

- Animation code should exist separately from game code. You really don't want your gameplay code too tightly tied to the nuts and bolts of animation playback.
- The animation code knows whether or not to loop based on the animation definition
- The animation code knows when the animation is done, and can call back to some other code to say 'hey, the animation called "fire" just finished, what do you want to do now?'
- The animation code doesn't know anything about events other than that they have a name and some arbitrary data associated with them (param1 and param2)
- The animation code knows what frame it's currently on, and when it changes to a new frame, it can check and say 'oh, I'm on frame 4 now, that means this event called "fire" has just happened, add that to my list of recent events so I can tell anyone who asks about it'.

If you don't need the bullet firing to happen within the animation, but only once it has finished, you can get away with a much less complex system without the notion of events. But you'll still want a system where animations play back on their own, know how long they are, and can call back to the game code when an animation completes.

Comment: I don't agree with keeping logic aware animations (on frame 4 now, that means this event called "fire" has just happened). Animations should be blind and dumb. I had to do some server side logics and tearing animations and UI out of a game is something I don't want to do again. I would really recommend using very short and segmented animations, play them in parallel to logics let the logics trigger animation sequences at the speed defined by the logics. Never have logics test for an animation's status.

Comment: Splitting the animation up into pieces seems pretty unnecessary. I would agree with not polling for the animation's status, but that still leaves his first recommendation. I don't know if he meant a separate event system to decouple the animation code from the rest of the game (observer pattern?) but that's how I'd do it. Neither the "logics" as you put it should know about the animation code, or vice versa.

Comment: @Coyote I'd say there you're mixing two separate things. Yes, server side logic should always be independent of visuals (because you don't want to have to run the animation system just to figure out when a bullet is fired), but that's not going to help you build an animation system on the client. On the client, you absolutely don't want the visuals to be mindlessly slaved to the server, because that would look awful - bullets appearing at odd times and out of sync with the character because there was a lag spike between the game and the server. There's no reason you can't have both (cont...)

Comment: @Coyote (cont...), the gameplay can be driven by the server decoupled from the visuals. So the bullet is fired at time X on the server, and the client mirrors that action by starting to play the fire animation immediately, with the bullet firing visual lagging a few frames behind the bullet gameplay simulation.

All sorts of compromises need to be made between visual fidelity and gameplay simulation, so to say that "animations should be blind and dumb" is simply naive. Sometimes events absolutely need to be tied to animation frames, because no other method will make them look or sound right.

Comment: @Coyote Actually now I think about it, the bullet firing is a terrible example for this, mostly because of the answer from thedaian below. Firing should happen straight away. A better example would be a dust VFX firing when a character lands - the server and client would sync as to when the character starts to jump, but the visual display is left up to the client. And when the animation hits the right frame where the foot hits the ground, the VFX event should fire. Similarly, events are needed if a decision needs to be made on a certain animation frame whether to branch to another animation.

Comment: @MrCranky: The dust FX should play on the client whenever the client needs it, it doesn't really need to be fully synced for the gameplay. As for bullets it's all about mitigating the delay management. They appear on the device when the the player fires and the server will propagate them to the other ones at the current position it will be up to the clients to play the animation and mitigate the visual lag on their side. Most games give you the impression of real time fire by playing the fire animation on your end immediately. But it doesn't work this way in MP implementations.

Comment: @MrCranky: ... but I agree that FX are rarely dumb :( I was simply pointing to the idea that a developer should strive to make them as dumb as possible (should not must). I try to use them as a service. When available they provide feedback to the logics, when not (standalone server) the logics runs without them and doesn't need to be adjusted and re-synced (which I consider cheating)

Comment: @MrCranky: Ow... And really I am absolutely **not** saying that animation should be slave to the server. I am saying that the animation should be slave to the logics... Wherever replicated or "proxyed" and adjusted to the input system on the client devices. Of course on the client implementation you don't want the display to lag... It would be terrible! I guess I wasn't clear. Sorry about the wording, I'm not a native English speaker. And I got carried away... I was referring to my answer... but didn't point it out. *shame*

Comment: @Coyote I think this is getting away from the OP (which is about visuals), but at some point you have to decide how your server is simulating actors. If it's always the clients supplying the actions (e.g. clientA tells serverX that they have fired), then it's fine (in fact healthy) to have the client-side animations driving events. The only time you'd run across the case you described would be if the server was simulating actors on its own. In which case it could still be animation driven, but it would certainly be simpler and more robust if it weren't.

Comment: @MrCranky: Right... :) You live in Edinburgh! That's a great place to live!

Answer (score 3):

In some way, you'll have to wait until the animation is done and create the bullet at that point.

Just setting a timer will work, if you're sure that your animation rate is fixed. As a minor variation, you could have code internal to the bullet that makes it wait invisibly for a moment before appearing and moving.

Depending on your development platform, you may have some sort of animation update function or callback that will let you respond the exact moment the animation reaches the desired point. This is how I'd do it with Flixel, for example.

Comment: Flixel's `addAnimationCallback` method can be used on the firing entity. In the callback function, you can see if the current frame of the firing animation is the frame that should create a bullet entity. If it is then you can add a bullet on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Straight forward answer: Assuming you have an animation that you want to play when the player hits the 'fire' button, and then have a bullet come out after it's done playing.  Ideally, you should avoid hard-coding the animation time, and fire the bullet when the animation completes (using a callback function or something, depending on your platform).  I can't think of any other method to do this that isn't overly complex.

Alternate Game Design answer: Unless there's a really, *really* good reason to do so, I would avoid having a delay from pressing the 'fire' button and having the bullet appear.  Unless the animation is really, really short (one or two frames, max, basically a muzzle flash), it's going to make the fire button response feel slow, and it will just get annoying to a typical player.  Even if you do decide to go with using an animation before the bullets come out (turn based RPGs and tactical games would be acceptable reasons to do this), I'd think about including a "turn off animations" option somewhere, to allow the game to move faster if the player wants.

Comment: Yeah don't make the fire react slowly. This is just like the common issue with jumping; animators make a big windup, but players expect to be airborne as soon as they tap the button.

Answer (score 2):

As MrCranky says ; keep animation and logics separated.

But most importantly, **logics must remain the master** part.

- When the fire button is pressed you should trigger the draw "**action**" in your character's state (logics).
- This action should trigger the drawing *animation* with all the parameters (time to live etc).
- Once the draw **action** is finished you can trigger the fire **action** (could fire once or more depending on the weapon)
- This action can generate bullets and trigger the fire *animation*.

Keep in mind that controlling the UI from the logics is the only way to ensure you will be able to keep, reuse and share your logics later (new renderer, new game, server version without a renderer...)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd use an event system (observer pattern?) to decouple pieces of the code. This isn't just for the animation, but certainly applies there. Then the animation code can simply say dispatchEvent(event) and some other part of the code listens for that event, without either part of the code needing to know about each other.

Now the animation code needs to actually have a reference to the event dispatcher (easily done with dependency injection) and you need to have some XML or JSON that actually defines your animations. Something like:

```
{
  animation: {
    name: shoot,
    length: 12,
    spritesheet: shoot.png
    event: {
      frame: 4,
      name: bulletLeavesGun,
    },
  },
}
```

Read in the data when loading the animation, and have the animation code dispatch the event when it's on that frame during playback.